# Compiling VBA code

Tags: vb6

Hi we use an old COM API which was written in VB6

I need to create a dll of some vba code

Is there a way I can compile this without having visual studio 6?

Thanks!

Comment: VB6 is not VBA, do not be fooled by those who will tell you that it is.  If you have a VB6 Project to compile you must have VB6.  About the only exception is that some VB6 code can be back-ported to VB5 easily, and then you might try compiling it with VB5.  VB5 can be even harder to come by legally though.

Comment: Do you have the source code? That would be a good start

Comment: Do you know what the public interface is to the VB6 dll?  You don't need a VB6 compiler if you wish to call function from a VB6 dll in VBA.  Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915.aspx